# AppStore: can I make an off-line alternative of in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I'm not sure if i ask this in a proper place, so please - direct me to the proper place if needed, and don't blame too much :)

I'm currently creating an app with a guide over on museum in St. Petersburg and my clients want it to cost some money, and they also want to sell brochures with code to activate in the app, so people receive the app even if they are not registered their bank card in itunes.

I know how to make that programmatically, but i'm not sure if that allowed by apple. Is it? Will i pass the review with such a feature?

Comment: Not sure, but probably not inside the app. Selling activations outside (like Spotify does) should be fine. Anyway, I've never seen the code-activation in an iOS app and I don't think asking for a code with a virtual keyboard is the correct way of doing things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about app-store approval. Read the tag info.

Comment: Rob, where should i ask it?